# How can I have text wrap in a child element of an element with nowrap?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem for set word-wrap:break-word. The result made this div showing scroll-x. But the problem is blockquote element not styling break-word anymore, it's stacking to the right direction.

How to make this thing work again?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

blockquote {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
  <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
  <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the point in having break-word: break-word if you want to have a horizontal scrolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that maybe you just need to restore the white-space setting for the blockquotes to `normal`. E.g.

```css
div {
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap; 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
blockquote {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:normal; 
}
```

```html
<div>
     <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
     <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
     <blockquote>balbalbalbalbalbablbalbalblbablblaabssddsdsblamlksdkdsllksdlskssdfsd</blockquote>
</div>
```

Or see http://jsfiddle.net/5f6zuxy3/

Answer (score 1):

Remove `white-space:nowrap;` from styling of `div`.

```
div {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4xfqa68/)**

**Update**

To place `blockquote` side by side and view it horizontally, remove `width:200px;` from blockquote

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hirume88/ctx3jbm1)**

Comment: thanks Samir for answering my question, i updated my question, would u like to at my filddle?

Comment: Removing `white-space:nowrap` will work for you. Updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ctx3jbm1/1/

Comment: i know it's working, but i dont want blockquote to break world into vertical, i want it to horizontal. so, if i want to look the other blockquote i will use scroll-x instead scroll-y

Comment: Got it now. Remove width from blockquote to avoid overlapping. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hirume88/ctx3jbm1/

Comment: thanks Samir for answering my question, btw, nothing change from that jsfiddle. anyway thank you!